# How to integrate swagger 2 with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-2.0

In my spring boot projects I'm using spring security with jwt token. 
How I'm integrated swagger 2.0 in my spring boot project

Comment: You are having issue with implementing Swagger 2 or you have implemented and facing some issue with Spring Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below link how to integrate swagger 2 with spring.

https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api